# how to remove navbar from certain react-routes i am using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having a side nav-bar which i want to show on all pages except some(not include login,signup etc other then them) so what i have done till now is as below

my App.js looks like this

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Main, Wrapper } from './App.styled';
import Login from 'Scenes/Login';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from 'Theme';
import Navigation from 'Components/Navbar';
import ForgotPassword from 'Scenes/ForgotPassword';
import ResetPassword from 'Scenes/ResetPassword';
import Dashboard from 'Scenes/DashBoard';
import Appointment from 'Scenes/Appointment';
import WaitingRoom from 'Scenes/WaitingRoomList';
import PatientList from 'Scenes/PatientList';
import UsersAndRoles from 'Scenes/Settings/UsersAndRoles';
import CreateAppointment from 'Scenes/CreateAppointment';
import AddUser from 'Scenes/Settings/AddUser';
import PasswordChange from 'Scenes/Settings/ChangePassword';
import PageHeader from 'Components/PageHeader';
import { TitleContext } from 'Constants/contextCreate';
import { checkToken } from 'Core/authentication';
import UserDetails from 'Scenes/User';
import Waiting from 'Scenes/User/WaitingRoom';
import RescheduleAppointment from 'Scenes/ScheduleRequestAppointment';
import MemberSignup from 'Scenes/MemberSignup';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import ComeNowPage from 'Scenes/User/ComeNow';

function App() {
    const [isNavbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = useState(false);

    const value = useContext(TitleContext);

    const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState(value.title);

    const loggedIn = checkToken();
    console.log(loggedIn, 'status of login ');
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Main>
                <ToastContainer />
                <Navigation
                    loggedIn={loggedIn}
                    isNavbarOpen={isNavbarOpen}
                    navControl={setNavbarOpen}
                />
                <TitleContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        title: pageTitle,
                        changeTitle: item => setPageTitle(item)
                    }}
                >
                    <Wrapper loggedIn={loggedIn}>
                        <PageHeader
                            loggedIn={loggedIn}
                            navControl={setNavbarOpen}
                        />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/forgot_password"
                                component={ForgotPassword}
                            />
                            {/* <Route
                                exact
                                path="/reset_password/:token"
                                component={ResetPassword}
                            /> */}
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/password/new"
                                component={ResetPassword}
                            />
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/appointments"
                                component={Appointment}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/appointments/create_new"
                                component={CreateAppointment}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/appointments/edit_appointment"
                                component={CreateAppointment}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/appointments/request/reschedule"
                                component={RescheduleAppointment}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/waiting_room"
                                component={WaitingRoom}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/patient_list"
                                component={PatientList}
                            />
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/settings/users_roles"
                                component={UsersAndRoles}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/settings/users_roles/add_user"
                                component={AddUser}
                            />

                            <Route
                                path="/settings/users_roles/edit_user"
                                component={AddUser}
                            />

                            <Route
                                path="/member/new/signup"
                                component={MemberSignup}
                            />

                            <Route
                                path="/settings/change_password"
                                component={PasswordChange}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/patient/request_appointment"
                                component={UserDetails}
                            />
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/patient/virtualwaiting_room"
                                component={Waiting}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/patient/virtualwaiting_room/come_now"
                                component={ComeNowPage}
                            />
                            <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                        </Switch>
                    </Wrapper>
                </TitleContext.Provider>
            </Main>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

now what i want is on the route /patient/request_appointment and /patient/virtualwaiting_room i don't want the navbar for login and signup what i had done is checked weather the token is exist or not, if exists then i showed up navbar else not but for these two routes i want to not show mnavbar either token exists or not, any help would be much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "useLocation" hook from the router-dom to check the path and programatically hide/unhide the navbar.

```
import {useLocation, useState} from 'react-router-dom'
        
const Navbar = ()=>{
  const [hide, setHide]=useState(false)
  let path = useLocation();
  if (path.pathname == '/patient/request_appointment' || path.pathname == ' /patient/virtualwaiting_room'){
     setHide(true)
}
}
```

Comment: useNavigation in RR6

Answer (score 0):

Easiest: You could set a conditional class, with display: none as CSS.